# Need to remind user of upcoming appointment (if any are scheduled), within 15 minutes, when logged into main screen of application

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, datagridview

I need to display a MessageBox telling the user that an appointment will be starting within 15 minutes of the start time of the appointment. The Main Screen of the application has an AppointmentsDataGridView that is filled with the information from the MySql appointments table. I need to somehow get the nearest starting appointment from the "start" column of the table once the user logs in and display a message box telling the user if there is an appointment starting within 15 minutes.

I have tried to loop through the `AppointmentsDataGridView` in the "start" index of 2 and try and pull the next upcoming time and show a MessageBox but it doesn't happen. The code shown is a radio button that populates the `AppointmentsDataGridView` when the `MainScreenForm` loads.

```
    private void AllAppointmentsRadioButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MySqlConnection con1 = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["U04i5a"].ConnectionString);
        MySqlCommand cmd1 = new MySqlCommand("SELECT appointmentId, customerId, start, end, type FROM appointment", con1);
        con1.Open();
        MySqlDataAdapter adapter1 = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd1);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        adapter1.Fill(dt);
        AppointmentsDataGridView.DataSource = dt;
        DateTime dtm = Convert.ToDateTime(dtptest.Text);
        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            if (dtm.ToShortTimeString().Equals(dt.Rows[i][1].ToString()))
            {
                MessageBox.Show(dtm.ToShortDateString());
                MessageBox.Show(dtm.ToShortTimeString());
                MessageBox.Show(dtm.ToShortDateString());
            }
            //indexes: 0= appointmentId, 1= customerId, 2= start, 3= end, 4= type
            dt.Rows[i][1] = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc((DateTime)dt.Rows[i][2], TimeZoneInfo.Local);
            dt.Rows[i][1] = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc((DateTime)dt.Rows[i][3], TimeZoneInfo.Local);
            TimeSpan duration = (DateTime)dt.Rows[i][2] - DateTime.Now;
            if (duration.TotalMinutes < 15)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("There is less than 15 minutes before your next appointment:" + dt.Rows[i][2]);
            }
        }
        //today = DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
        //15 minute remider might be here?
        AppointmentsDataGridView.Columns[0].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
        con1.Close();
        AppointmentsDataGridView.ClearSelection();
        AppointmentsDataGridView.CurrentCell = null;
        AppointmentsDataGridView.Update();
        AppointmentsDataGridView.Refresh();
    }
```

Format of "start" column in from MySql DB in DateTime "2019-05-28 13:00:46"

The needed MessageBox doesn't show.

Comment: You need to debug the code and see what values you are getting in `duration.TotalMinutes`

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have UTC dates in your data table, that you try to convert to local time, but you set the customerId column both times (`dt.Rows[i][1]`)? Then you try to subtract DateTime.Now from the UTC start time, which depending on the time zone won't work. Use either `DateTime.UtcNow` for the duration or set the local time in the DataTable.

Comment: Hi Jeremy, thank you for the advice and yes you are correct about the the times. However, I need to change the approach because I need to query the DB table to satisfy the requirements.